# Cast as Date Only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My goal is to display this

```
02/28/19 63
```

from this. (date_birth is datetime in DB)

```
1963-02-28 00:00:00.000
```

I used this SQL query code

```
FORMAT(date_birth,'MM/dd/19 yy')
```

but my teacher wanted it in a cast so I did this

```
CAST(date_birth as date) as date_birth
```

How can i format the above date through cast?

Comment: is `date_birth` already a DateTime column in the DB?

Comment: @blurfus yes Sir/Maam.

Comment: So you are casting a DateTime into Date and *then* you want to format it... maybe something like `FORMAT(CAST(date_birth as DATE),'MM/dd/19 yy')` might work

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format, they are binary values. It's up to the presentation layer to determine the presented format, not the RDBMS.

Comment: You wrote `CAST(date_birth as date) as date_birth` - please note that it is probably a bad idea to use `date_birth` in both places, as they are not the same thing.

Comment: @blurfus yes Sir/Maam. The whole instruction is "I would like for you to display the date_birth as date only field for this you need to use cast function".

Comment: @Andre Morton isnt "as date_birth" is just the column name you wanted?

Comment: @blurfus Sir/Maam this works thank you.

Comment: @Claud30 No, the name of the "As" thing needs to be different from any other variable or column name or anything else.

Comment: @AndrewMorton noted Sir. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `date_birth` is already a `DateTime` column in the DB, you can *chain* the function calls and call them together.

Something like this: `FORMAT(CAST(date_birth as DATE),'MM/dd/19 yy')`

Please note that the order matters here - also, if `date_birth` is a `VARCHAR` in the DB, then this might not work as the contents of the string could be different from something a `Date` could accept.

For info: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-system-functions/convert-datetime-to-date/